# Linux video conversion

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to create a simple video conversion app which accepts any video format and then formats it into the desired format "automagically" all while attempting to keep aspect ratio and sound quality consistent.  I do a ton of video converting and it would be handy for me to just shoot it off to a server to do all the converting while I work on other projects.

After some research it looks like FFMPEG is my best bet ...

Anyone have any thoughts? Is there a open source project that has already done this / code that I might have missed or looked over?

Comment: google cloud + video transcoding; you'll see that this is not exactly new territory; do you really want to host this yourself?

Comment: Not really ... could you explain a little more about what you are thinking? Also any thoughts on this article (http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/26cf047a13815a2e?pli=1)?

Comment: gstreamer - http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I donot recommend hosting such a service yourself. I think you should be able to find 'off-the-shelf' cloud provider with 'instant' transcoding machines on-demand.

You are not looking for application hosting, such as GAE, you are looking for **P** aaS (Platform as a Service), such as Azure, AWS EC2; Here is a good comparison:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64727/windows-azure-vs-amazon-ec2-vs-google-app-engine (note the answer by a GAE developer).

Basically, PaaS should be able to deliver you computing units (where you are specifically **expected** to utilize the full CPU (etc) potential of the instance - after that, you just terminate the instance; you pay by the hour, and you scale up as required; You can equally good run 1 small instance for a month, or run 60 large instances for a few hours and work out the financial equation).

I do remember seeing pre-existing cloud images precisely for doing video transcoding - don't remember where exactly, but look around at [rightscale.com](http://rightscale.com) (which works with Rackspace and EC2 IIRC, perhaps more these days).

Answer (score 0):

[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is easily the best choice for this. I [use ffmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pydlnadms/source/browse/pydlnadms.py#489) in my [Python DLNA Digital Media Server](http://code.google.com/p/pydlnadms/) to convert video files of any kind to the [type expected by my television](http://code.google.com/p/pydlnadms/source/browse/pydlnadms.py#508).

I've had a play with [VLC's dummy interface](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode), and [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/mencoder.html), and neither came close to ffmpeg's usability.